# RadioButton doesn't get current value from model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, ienumerable

My model is IEnumerable<> of RatingSource.

```
public class RatingSource
    {
        public int Id;

        public string Source;

        public bool IsActive;
```

In the view I want to see 2 columns: Source and radioButton, cheked if IsActive is true. I write:

```
@foreach (var ratingSource in Model)
 {
     <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => ratingSource.Source) @Html.RadioButton("Active",ratingSource.IsActive) <br />
        </td>
     </tr>
 }
```

But radioButtons are always unchecked. Where is a mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => ratingSource.IsActive)
```

You could also try

```
@Html.RadioButton("IsActive",ratingSource.IsActive)
```

EDIT:

```
@Html.RadioButton("Active", ratingSource.Id, ratingSource.IsActive)
```

This works, however, since radiobuttons are mutually exclusive, the last 1 that is active will be the one checked.

Comment: If I write @Html.RadioButton("smth",true) radioButton is also unchecked

Comment: Thank u. 3rd variant works. But now I don't understand what is mean the 2nd argument

Comment: that is the value that would be posted back in for the form collection

Comment: @Stalli - It's id of control.