# All radioButtons are false at the view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

```
@Html.RadioButton("smth",true)
```

This row at the page looks like UNCHECKED radioButton. Why?

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
HtmlHelper.RadioButton(string name, object value, bool isChecked)
```

extension method.

**First argument** is the name of the form field which is input field generated by html helper.

**Second argument** is the value of input element. If this radio is selected when the postback to server happens, this value is used.

**Third argument** is what you are looking for. If it is true it makes radio button selected.

---

For instance,

```
@Html.RadioButton("Name", "Value" ,true)
```

would generate an input element which looks like following,

```
<input checked="checked" id="Name" name="Name" type="radio" value="Value" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use something of the form

```
@Html.RadioButton(id,value,checked (bool true/false))
```

So

```
@Html.RadioButton("A","B",true)
```

For example would produce:

```
  <input checked="checked" id="A" name="A" type="radio" value="B" />
```

The documentation for this is **[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee830431%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)**

Answer (score 0):

### **[In your previous query, you got this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16588440/2377970)**.

You asked the same query in it's comment section. The problem was that the second line of code was missing one parameter.

Please check below details....

### **Parameter Details**

[image]

### **Razor Syntax**

```
@Html.RadioButton("smth", "smth", true)

@Html.RadioButtonFor( m => m.Prop, true, new { id = "rdBtn" } )
```